# How to find scaling factor for new data in R?

Tags: r

I developed a model for my fraud detection dataset that contains 100000 records.

In my dataset, I treated 70% of the data as training data and 30% of the data as testing data. Before generating a final model for the training data, I then scaled the data using `scale=TRUE` in R.

But I can't scale the prediction (i.e., testing) data alone.

How do I scale the new data?

Comment: This is a bit vague - please provide a reproducible example. What is the model? To which function are you passing the arg `scale=TRUE`?

Comment: The model is logistic regression and I am passing it to glm().

Comment: AFAIK `scale` isn't an argument to [`glm`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/glm.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to scale the new vector (`v2`) using the centring and scaling parameters used to scale the original vector (`v1`) you can do:

```
v1 <- 1:10
v1_scl <- scale(v1)
```

```
v2 <- sample(20, 10)
v2_scl <- (v2 - attr(v1_scl, 'scaled:center')) / attr(v1_scl, 'scaled:scale')
```

or if you've used the default of centring `v1` on its mean and scaling by its standard deviation, you can do:

```
v2_scl <- (v2 - mean(v1)) / sd(v1)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but here the mean and standard deviations of v1,v2 may be different.In that case how can we consider v1's mean and S.D to scale v2?

Comment: @user3131969: For the linear predictor `logit_p[i] <- b0 + b1*x[i] + eps[i]`, if `x` is centered on its mean and scaled by 1 standard deviation, then the coefficient `b1` describes the change in `logit_p` that corresponds to an `sd(x)` increase in `x`. This remains true when predicting to new data, so those new data should be scaled similarly, i.e. in terms of the mean and sd of `x`.

Comment: In other words, the data to which the model is fitted, and data with which the response is predicted using the model, should be on the same scale.

Comment: Okay,but If we take transactions as one of the vector in fraud detection data set the transaction amount varies from account to account.For user1 transaction amount is 100$ and user2 amount is 100000$.Is this type of data suitable to logistic regression or not?

Comment: @user3131969: That question is more suited to [stats.se] and will require more explanation from you, but if you want to fit a model using transaction data for one user, and predict to the transaction data for other users, the data must all be expressed on the same scale (whether this is dollars, thousands of dollars, standard deviations of the pooled set of training data, etc.). Fitting to a subset of data that is not representative of the data to which you will predict to will probably require extrapolation, which may or may not be reliable.

Comment: I am implementing a logit model on fraud detection data set which is having several attributes.Target column is truth or fraud.Data contains transaction amount is one of  attributes.I generally scale the data before going to model it.So, now training data is scaled on mean and SD.If new records comes to predict that model which is having different mean and SD how can I scale based on old training data?.

Comment: @user3131969: Exactly as I described in my answer. For the model to predict (the probability of) fraud for new transaction amount (etc.) data, the new data must be on the same scale as the data used to fit the model. In other words, a unit change in the new data must mean the same thing (e.g. the same dollar amount) as a unit change in the model-fitting data. So if you scaled the model-fitting data by subtracting their mean and dividing by their standard deviation, for example, then you need to subtract _that same mean_ from the new data, and divide by _that same sd_.

Comment: @user3131969: If this doesn't make sense, please consider posting a question (after checking if it's already been answered) at [stats.se]. I've shown _how_ to do it, but if you have questions about the appropriateness of the model, or underlying theory about model-fitting and prediction, that's outside the scope of SO.

Comment: Okay thank you very much.I try your code to find new scale.But I need to check how it effects on accuracy of prediction.